# changing image of imagebutton till it is pressed

Tags: android, imagebutton

I want that in my android application, the ImageButton change its image when it is pressed and released, and when it is pressed released again, the image for ImageButton will be changed back , how to do that? 
I have tried  it with selector.
But it is not working.
Please anyone help me.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the following selector.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <item 
    android:state_pressed="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/pressedImage"/>
  <item 
    android:state_focused="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/normalImage"/>
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/normalImage"/>
</selector>
```

Comment: check my edited code, there might be some programatic mistakes, but all you need it logic.

Comment: with this code the image remained the same even after it is released. I want that when the image is presed till the moment it is pressed the image changes. and when it is released its resource again sets to the original image...

Comment: please change your question then, it gives a different meaning when i read.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3545/discussion-between-ekjyot-and-yashwanth-kumar)

Answer (score 5):

**make file in drawable folder a.xml ::**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item
    android:state_pressed="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/oneImage" />
  <item
    android:state_pressed="false"
    android:drawable="@drawable/secondImage" />
</selector>
```

**and in your main file :: button have implment following code ::**

```
<ImageButton android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="anything"
        android:id="@+id/first"
        android:background="@drawable/a"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" 
        android:textStyle="bold"
        ></ImageButton>
```

Comment: doesn't this code mean, when you press the image changes to oneImage and when there is no press the image is secondImge? , I think the question is different.

Comment: when you press it surely change image

Comment: It is giving me exception failed to parse selector.xml file